# Primary key value from SQL function

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have written a user defined function in SQL to generate random integers to be used as a primary key:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[GetNewID]
AS
SELECT ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) AS new_id;

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RandomID] ()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @new_id AS INT
    SET @new_id = (SELECT new_id FROM GetNewID)

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Foo WHERE FooID = @new_id) != 0
        SELECT @new_id = [dbo].[RandomID]()

    RETURN @new_id
END;
```

With the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo] (
    [FooID] [int] PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT([dbo].[RandomID]()),
    [val] [varchar](32)
);
```

Using SQL to insert records works as expected.

However when attempt to create a new record with LINQ I get the following error:

> Cannot insert the value Null into column id, column does not allow nulls

In my LINQ to SQL model `FooID` has the following column attributes:

```
[ColumnAttribute(Storage="_FooID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
```

If I check the SQL generated by LINQ the problem is pretty clear:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Foo]([val])
VALUES (@p0)

SELECT CONVERT(Int,SCOPE_IDENTITY()) AS [value]
-- @p0: Input VarChar (Size = 8000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Testing]
```

LINQ is trying to get the last value from an identity insert which will return null.

So I suppose the question comes down to; can I have an auto-generated primary key property in LINQ that does **NOT** use an identity column in the underlying SQL? Is there another approach I could take that would yield the same result?

Note: I would like to avoid changing application code. Ideally this should *Just Work* when changing my existing tables from using a linear increment primary key to a randomly generated one.

Answer (score 1):

In the DBML designer, set the `Auto Generated Value` property to `true` for that column. That should do the trick.

Check [this post](http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2009/2/6/using-default-values-in-linq-to-sql.aspx), and [this thread in the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/06bc58e9-5078-41a2-8c55-edff8467ba70/)

Comment: In my post you'll see that it's already set to true. The problem is LINQ to SQL assumes it's an identity insert and tries to get the auto-generated value with SCOPE_IDENTITY().